# Im trying to populate my form with data from my database base on a search

Tags: php, forms

Im tying to populate my form with data from my database by on a search.

Basically It's Like this,

**Search Page****

-The will be a searching form here where I will input  the primary key. Lets say Im Using Last Name-

**End Search Page****

**Form Editing Page****

Here I want the form to be populated with data that is on the same row with my  Primary Key.

**End Form Editing Page****

I can take care of the HTML but for the Logic and PHP part Im quite lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For form editing page : Before html starts do the query using php and my sql, and store the query results to php variables.Then using `value=<?php echo $queryresult?>` you can display the values.

P.S post the userid to this page. Do the query based on the post variable.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I ensure the data will  append the database and will not instead create a new line on the database. Dou you know any tutorial about this ?

Comment: You have to do query of `select(your coloums)` select query will not add new rows.

Comment: could you give me an example as im still learning abaout this, thanks

Comment: ex. 
`<?php 
 $this->db->select('*'); 
  $query = $this->db->from ( Your table name );
  $this->db->where ( dbcolumn=search query ); 
$query= $this->db->get ( "");
foreach ( $query->result_array () as $val ) 
{
$var=$val[your need column]
} 
 
?>`In html
`<intput type="text" value="<?php echo $var;?>">`